# ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

Tags: mysql, database, controller, nestjs, typeorm

I am new to nest js. So what I am trying to do here is a user has only one role. so I have to create an endpoint as users/:id/link-role

roles-entity

```
import { Company } from 'src/company/entities/company.entity';
import { Entitlement } from 'src/entitlement/entities/entitlement.entity';
import { BaseTable } from 'src/shared/base-table';
import { User } from 'src/user/entities/user.entity';
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  ManyToOne,
} from 'typeorm';
import { RoleType } from '../enum/roles.enum';

@Entity()
export class Role extends BaseTable {
  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: RoleType,
  })
  roles: RoleType;

  @Column({ name: 'description' })
  description: string;
  entitlement: any;

  @ManyToMany(() => Entitlement, { eager: true })
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'role-entitlements',
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'role_id',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'entitlement_id',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
  })
  entitlements: Entitlement[];

  @ManyToOne(() => User)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  users: User[];

  @ManyToOne(() => Company, (company) => company.roles)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'company_id' })
  company: Company;
}
```

user-entity

```
import { Company } from 'src/company/entities/company.entity';
import { NegativeEntitlement } from 'src/entitlement/entities/negative-entitlement.entity';
import { PositiveEntitlement } from 'src/entitlement/entities/positive-entitlement.entity';
import { BaseTable } from 'src/shared/base-table';
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  OneToMany,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class User extends BaseTable {
  @Column({ name: 'first_name', length: 100 })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({ name: 'middle_name', length: 100 })
  middleName: string;

  @Column({ name: 'last_name', length: 100 })
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ name: 'preferred_name', length: 100 })
  preferredName: string;

  @Column({ name: 'email', length: 320 })
  email: string;

  @Column({ name: 'phone', length: 20 })
  phone: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Company)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'user_companies',
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'user_id',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'company_id',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
  })
  companies: Company[];

  @OneToMany(
    () => PositiveEntitlement,
    (positiveEntitlements) => positiveEntitlements.user,
  )
  positiveEntitlements: PositiveEntitlement[];

  @OneToMany(
    () => NegativeEntitlement,
    (negativeEntitlements) => negativeEntitlements.user,
  )
  negativeEntitlements: NegativeEntitlement[];
}
```

Now, In user-service I have created a function to get a user and role which in return links role to user

```
async addRole(id: string, addRoleDto: AddRoleDto) {
    const currUser: User = await this.findAndValidateUser(id);
    console.log('currentUser: ', currUser);
    const role: Role = await this.rolesService.findAndValidateRole(
      addRoleDto.roleId,
    );
    console.log('role:', role);
    console.log('users: ', role.users);
    const users: User[] = role.users.filter((user) => user.id == currUser.id);

    if (users.length > 0) {
      return new CustomException('user already has a role');
    }
    role.users = role.users.concat(currUser);
    await this.rolesRepository.save(role);
  }
```

In the function above I am trying to find if the user already has that particular role if true return exception if false the concatenate the current user to the array.
I am getting the following error as mentioned above. I am not able to understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeORM doesn't load relations by default, you either have to specify them when you query the data or mark the relations as eager, which would result in loading them automatically every time.

In your case, `users` is a `ManyToOne` relation in `Role`. I imagine somewhere in `roleService.findAndValidateRole` you load the role by doing this:

```ts
const role = await Role.findOne(roleId, { 
  relations: 'users' // add this
});
```

You can also mark the relation as `eager`, but **mind that it will load users every time**, and you might not want that. If you have eager relations everywhere, your app will put a lot of stress on the database by loading data unnecessarily, and your app will eventually become very slow.

```ts
@Entity()
export class Role extends BaseTable {
  // ...

  @ManyToOne(() => User, { eager: true }) // add this
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  users: User[];

  // ...
}
```